# Double parameter with 2 digits after dot in strings.xml?

Tags: android, string, android-resources, formatter

I want to have a parameter in one string in `strings.xml` and this parameter should be a double value. So I use `%1$f`. Here - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html there are many examples, but what if I want to have have a few `double/float` parameters and I want only the second one to have 2 digits after `.`? I tried to use combinations like `%2$.2f` or `%2.2$f`. Nor of them worked. `%.1f` does not work as well.
So, does anybody know how can I "customize" a `float/double` value inside a `strings.xml`? Thanks.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Just adding to @David Airam's answer here; the "incorrect" solution he gives is actually correct, but with a bit of tweaking. The XML file should contain:

```
<string name="resource1">Hello string: %1$s, and hello float: %2$.2f.</string>
```

Now in the Java code:

```
String svalue = "test";
float sfloat= 3.1415926;
String sresult = getString(R.string.resource1, svalue, sfloat);
```

The exception that @David Airam reported is from trying to jam a `String` into a format specifier with `%f`, which requires a floating point type. Use `float` and there is no such exception.

Also, you can use `Float.valueOf()` to convert a String to a float in case your input data was originally a string (say, from a `EditText` or something). However, you should *always* try/catch `valueOf()` operations and handle the `NumberFormatException` case, since this exception is unchecked.

Answer (score 9):

%.1f work for me if you like to show only 1 digit after ','

Answer (score 4):

Define is strings.xml file

```
  <string name="price_format">$%,.2f</string>

//For using in databinding  where amount is double type
    android:text="@{@string/price_format(model.amount)}"

//For using in java runtime where priceOfModifier is double type
                amountEt.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.price_format, priceOfModifier));
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach:

`<string name="decimalunit">%.2f%n</string>`

`float sfloat= 3.1475926;`
`String sresult = getString(R.string.decimalunit, sfloat);`

Output: 3.15

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<string name="market_price">Range ₹%1$.0f - ₹%2$.0f</string>
```

```
android:text="@{@string/market_price(viewModel.suggestedPriceRange.max, viewModel.suggestedPriceRange.min)}"
```

Outputs: `Range ₹500 - ₹1000`

In `₹%1$.0f`, `.0f` defines how many digits you want after the decimal.

Answer (score -6):

If it were me I'd store the values in the resources as simple values, and then use formatter methods to control how they're displayed, roughly like this

```
public String formatFigureTwoPlaces(float value) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
    return myFormatter.format(value);
}

public String formatFigureOnePlace(float value) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.0");
    return myFormatter.format(value);
}
```

Comment: The comment here is the real answer! You should put it as another answer to this question. I almost didn't see it.

Comment: the answer by Iomza in the comments is the real solution

Answer (score -6):

I now that this reply is arriving too late... but I hope to be able to help other people:

Android sucks with multiple parameters substitutions when you want decimal numbers and format this in common style %a.bf

The best solution I have found (and only for these kind of resources) is put the decimal parameters as strings %n$s and in the code apply my conversion with String.format(...)

*Example:*

**INCORRECT WAY:**

// In xml file:

```
<string name="resource1">You has a desviation of %1$s and that is a %2$.2f%% percentage.</string>
```

// And in java file

```
  String sresult = getString(R.string.resource1, svalue, spercentage); // <-- exception!
```

This solution is technically correct but incorrect due to android substitution resources system so **the last line will generate an exception.**

**CORRECT WAY / SOLUTION:**

Simply convert the second parameter into a String.

```
<string name="resource1">You has a desviation of %1$s and that is a %2$s percentage.</string>
```

And now in the code:

```
...

  // This is the auxiliar line added to solve the problem
  String spercentage = String.format("%.2f%%",percentage);

  // This is the common code where we use the last variable.
  String sresult = getString(R.string.resource1, svalue, spercentage);
```

Comment: What is the type of `spercentage` in your "incorrect" example? I'm guessing (as @Nik Reiman points out) that it's a `String` - i.e. no wonder you're getting an exception when trying to pass it as a float (at `%2$.2f`). This "answer" is incomplete and misleading.

Comment: I also can't get formatted floats to work from a string resource, and yes I'm passing a float.  I use "%1$0.6f" in the string resource, and I get an exception: java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %01$.6f  so it's getting mangled somehow.  This answer is correct.