# Result with 2 digits after . eg:23.65

Tags: java, android

I want to do some calculations on my app the result will mostly have from 5 to 15 digits after the . for example `24.61835496354822` I want to display the result in a `TextView` and only show 2 digits after `.` for example `24.61` please help me

Comment: go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820149/double-parameter-with-2-digits-after-dot-in-strings-xml?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820149/double-parameter-with-2-digits-after-dot-in-strings-xml?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double d = 24.61835496354822;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

Comment: how can I display the result on a TextView?

Comment: textview.setText(valueOf(f.format(d)));

Answer (score 0):

Either use System.out.printf("%.2f", val);` or

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(df.format(decimalNumber));

new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
import java.text.*;  
 class Decimals {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    float f = 24.61835496354822f;  
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");  
    System.out.println(form.format(f));  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple string format like:

```
String.format("My value is: %.2f",  myFpVal));
```

If you just want the value, you can make your format string contain just the format instruction like:

```
String.format("%.2f",  myFpVal));
```