# Android Format Decimal Number using XML

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to format the number with 2 decimal places. I don't know why my code is receiving an error.

this is my code.

**strings.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="progress">%1$d / %2$d (%3.2f%%)</string>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
int progressCount;
int totalCount = 3000;
double percentage;

for (int x = 0; x < totalCount; x++) {
   progressCount = x;
   percentage = ((((double) progressCount) / ((double) totalCount)) * 100);
   Log.i("MainActivity", "Percentage: " + String.format(getString(R.string.progress), progressCount, totalCount, percentage));
}
```

**Error encounter:**

> Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format java.lang.Integer arguments

I want the output like this. **1/100 (0.01%)**

Comment: I think it must be (%3$.2f%%) instead of (%3.2f%%) in your resource string. Please, refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32755921/1803222 .

Comment: wow Thanks. but why it is not working without a **$** sign?

Comment: As far as I understand, %3$ part helps the system to identify that 3th passed parameter will be used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
 <string name="progress">%1$d / %2$d (%3.2f%%)</string>
```

with

```
 <string name="progress">%1$d / %2$d (%3$.2f)</string>
```