# Displaying Java float variable in XML TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an app in Android Stdio that runs a calculation. The calculation is on the Java side and outputs a float variable. I want a TextView on the XML side to display that Java float variable.

I tried making a XML string value with %1%d on it, but couldn't find what to put on the Java side. Otherwise I haven't found any other ways to fo it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double parameter with 2 digits after dot in strings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820149/double-parameter-with-2-digits-after-dot-in-strings-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps

1. In your XML layout, add a TextView element to display the float value. Make sure to give it an unique ID so you can reference it in your Java code
   like follows

Later you should following code in your Java class

```
// Assuming you have your float value
float myFloat = 123.45f;

// Find the TextView by its ID
TextView floatTextView = findViewById(R.id.floatTextView);

// Format the float value and set it in the TextView
String formattedFloat = String.format("%.2f", myFloat); // %.2f for two decimal places
floatTextView.setText("Float Value: " + formattedFloat);
```

In short we have used  String.format() method

Answer (score 0):

If your XML layout uses a format like `android:text="@string/my_result"` and you have a string defined like `<string name="my_result">Result = %1$.2f</string>`, then in Java, use this to set the text to your calculation result in `theResult`:

```
myView.setText(getString(R.string.my_result, theResult));
```